# I want to open a new form by clicking a button in oracle apps 11i

Tags: triggers, oracleforms, oracle-apps

I want to open e new form (Called Form) using a button from an existing form (Parent Form) in Oracle Apps 11i. Is this possible using "When-Button-Pressed" trigger? if not then please mention the other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible and suitable place. You can open a new form with either native Oracle Forms commands (OPEN_FORM or CALL_FORM) (not recommended in the Oracle EBS) or with FND_FUNCTION.EXECUTE. Please see instructions from the developer's guide how to use FND_FUNCTION.EXECUTE: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A99488_01/acrobat/115devg.pdf

Comment: I have added a button item in the Form's Data block and then wrote a When-button-pressed trigger using FND_FUNCTION.EXECUTE. But now while i am pressing the button in the form I'm getting an error message "Function not available to this responsibility".